# Forming Custom Linked Lists in Hadoop using Java

Tags: java, hadoop, linked-list, mapreduce, custom-data-type

I am new to Hadoop programming. Sorry if this is a silly question, but please help me.

For my project I need to form a Custom data type with linked list for value in (key,value) pair. Here is my class.

```
public class Nikhil implements Writable {
  String str;
  Nikhil next;
  Nikhil() {
    this.str="";
    this.next=null;
  }

  public void add(String t) {
    if(this.str.equals("")) {
      this.str=t;
      this.next=null;
      return;
    } else {
      Nikhil n=new Nikhil();
      n.str=t;
      n.next=null;
      Nikhil temp=this;
      while(temp.next!=null)
      {
        temp=temp.next;
      }
      temp.next=n;
      return;
    }
  }

  public String get()
  {
    if(!this.str.toString().equals(""))
    {
      String result="";
      result=this.str.toString();
      Nikhil temp=this.next;
      while(temp!=null)
      {
        result=result+","+temp.str.toString();
        temp=temp.next;
      }
      return result;
    }
    else
      return "";
  }

  @Override
  public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    str=in.readUTF();
    //some code for reading next pointer
  }

  @Override
  public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeUTF(str);
    //some code for next
    //
  }
}
```

please correct the following code and help me for solving my problem.What is the approach for forming trees as custom data types in hadoop.

Comment: I don't see anything related to Hadoop in your code, just Java.

Comment: This is the custom data type I am using in my mappper value to send to reducer.I am confused with the readFields and write function in the above code

Comment: Do you have a _question_?  What's wrong with the code you already have?  If there's a compilation error, what is it?  If there's a runtime exception, what was the stack trace?  If it ran but did something wrong, what did it do, and what were you expecting it to do?  (Also, what do trees have to do with any of this?  If that last sentence starts a separate question, then ask it in a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        str = in.readUTF();
        //some code for reading next pointer
        if (!"".equals(str)) {
            boolean existNext = in.readBoolean();
            if (existNext) {
                next = new Nikhil();
                next.readFields(in);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeUTF(str);
        //some code for next
        //
        if (!"".equals(str)) {
            boolean existNext = null != next;
            out.writeBoolean(existNext);
            if (existNext) {
                next.write(out);
            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe the above code is what you want. but other part of your code,especially add() , is not so strict. You'd better do more optimization.